# Setting up proxy_pass on nginx to make API calls to API Gateway

Tags: nginx, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

## Problem:

I've set up a Lambda function behind API gateway which works beautifully. I have a hosted site that I want only a certain location to hit the API.

#### Example

https://www.example.com/ (Serves up html from hosted server)

https://www.example.com/foobar (Returns a JSON payload that is generated by Lambda and returned by AWS)

Here is my server block:

```
   location = /foobar {
            proxy_pass     https://someawsuri;
            proxy_redirect default;
    }

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

I've tried reviewing the docs and read multiple SO posts, but I haven't been able to do what I want. Everything that I've tried has produced the error `502 Bad Gateway`.

## Question:

How do I configure nginx to make a request to API gateway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need those two lines:

```
proxy_set_header Host "XXXXXX.execute-api.REGION.amazonaws.com";
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

Here is the explanation about the why:

The `HOST` header is required as is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/making-http-requests/)

> The Amazon API Gateway endpoint. This value must be one of the region-dependent endpoints listed under [Regions and Endpoints.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#apigateway_region) In the US East (N. Virginia) region, it is apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

The [`proxy_ssl_server_name on;`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_server_name)

> Enables passing of the server name through TLS Server Name Indication extension (SNI) when establishing a connection with the proxied HTTPS server.